# sql server logic to workout the right most position of the numeric field will have a sign OVER it designating positive or negative

Tags: sql, layout, syntax

Example of the data in csv

Column_header

000000025000{

000000007185E

The doucmention I have

*The right most position of the numeric field will have a sign OVER it
designating positive or negative.

[image]
Example of Data

[image: Text]

I dont understand how write the logic to support the the symbol,number,letter to get the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a table (or view) with the static mapping of character-value, meaning:

| Symbol | Value |
| --- | --- |
| J | -1 |
| A | +1 |

about the data rows themselves, it seems to me there is always a symbol at the end, therefore you can split the data into two columns, value, and symbol...

I have no idea about how the data are inserted but it seems logically easy

```
SELECT
   _YourValue_
  ,LEFT(_YourValue_, LENGTH(_YourValue_)-1) as Value
  ,RIGHT(_YourValue_, 1) as Symbol
FROM _Whatever_
```

you can also cast to whatever datatype is correct for those data.
Finally you can join the tables and show/calculate whatever is needed

Answer (score 1):

```
select value , if(value LIKE '%{%' or value LIKE '%J%' or value LIKE '%E%' or value LIKE '%C%',concat(SUBSTRING(value,1,char_length(value)-1),'+'),concat(SUBSTRING(value,1,char_length(value)-1),'-')) as new_value from yourtablename
```

Output

| value | New Value |
| --- | --- |
| 000000025000{ | 000000025000+ |
| 000000007185E | 000000007185+ |

Add all other character on first parameter of if clause for positive designation.